Looking for an online course
I work for a company with expertise in electromagnetics physics, specifically dealing with time domain-based simulation software. We routinely need to transform our results into frequency domain, which we do performing FFTs, but we often need to manipulate our data in order to get valid frequency data, and our knowledge of digital signal processing is somewhat lackluster. For example, we may want to do more with windows to address some of the peculiarities of our simulation results, and we would like to learn more about it. Or we may need to interpolate and/or decimate very unevenly-spaced data sets, and we don't want to accidentally mess up the frequency domain results by doing so.
I am looking for an online educational resource that can be used for internal training. A lot of courses I find are very theoretical. For example, this MIT course is certainly very rigorous, but we probably don't need to learn the intricacies of the z-transform to know how to properly apply a flat-top window to our data sets. On the other end of the spectrum (pun intended) are many courses on youtube/coursera, or similar, which might touch upon subjects more directly applicable to our needs, but come with a lot of unknown about their quality.
Could anybody recommend any course which strikes a good balance between theoretical knowledge and practical use, which can be followed online? Free or not. I can provide more details of what we are looking for if my description was too vague.
Thank you very much in advance!

I'd somewhat disagree about your assessment regarding the z-transform, that is really fundamental to understanding discrete-time systems. Alan Oppenheim's course is already very compressed. For example, my "signals and systems" course was 13 weeks of 1.5 hr lecture every week and another 1.5 hr lecture every odd, or 1.5 hr hall exercise every even week, if I remember correctly; not saying that you'd need all that, but that compressing the material even further would probably make it very challenging to understand. I do think that as seminal as that phase was, I think a slightly more modern

might be nice; being able to just plot a few curves to illustrate a point is certainly something MIT didn't have in 1975 (what they did have was marvellous ties and excellent mustaches, it seems!)

I'm may be biased since I am the instructor, but I highly recommend the online course "DSP for Wireless Communications" which is offered routinely through dsprelated.com and the Boston Section IEEE. The course is offered as 15 hours of pre-recorded videos that you can watch at your own pace, combined with weekly live Q&A sessions with me over 5 weeks along with plenty of examples in Python Jupyter Notebooks. Links below:
https://ieeeboston.org/courses/
https://dsprelated.com/courses
Even though the title is "Wireless Communications" (as that is my background and perspective), the course really is a deep dive through practical DSP concepts applicable to many other fields with the right balance between theoretical details and practical application. I provide a very intuitive view not found elsewhere in bringing DSP concepts together including generalized signal processing (analog and mixed signal), including the benefit of actually understanding the intricacies of the wonderful z-transform - in a motivating way you've probably never seen explained. I hope to see you there!

